# Rich link preview in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is it possible to make a preview from an url, grabbing all the information such as title, relevant texts and images. Is there any plugins I can use readily?

See this [Native android plugin](https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way :

1)Create a user at https://www.linkpreview.net

2)Generate an Access Key.

3)From your code call

```
 http://api.linkpreview.net/?key=<Your_API_KEY_From_Step_2>&q=https://www.google.com
```

It returns the meta tags in JSON as below :

```
 {"title":"Google","description":"Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for.","image":"http:\/\/www.google.com\/images\/branding\/googlelogo\/1x\/googlelogo_white_background_color_272x92dp.png","url":"https:\/\/www.google.com\/"}
```

4) Use it in flutter widget to create a preview.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not late to answer this question, There is a plugin for link with previews [Rich link preview](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_link_preview)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, **there is not an open source library** for flutter providing these meta tags for a website.

There is a **temporal solution**, using these **freemium APIs** for getting this information. The main drawback is that the requests are limited before paying.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but I found a solution for that.

The [comment of Sudip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53719751/12066144) might work but if you have a lot of preview to generate, you will have to subscribe and pay..

I couldn't use the library [rich_link_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/rich_link_preview) because of some depency issues (it requires `http < 1.12.0`).

So I had to do it myself. Writting the complete answer in this comment would be too long so I'll tell you how I did it.
I followed [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZQ4Ddtz2A4). If you are too lazy to watch the entire video you can look at his [Github Repo](https://github.com/prolongservices/Flutter-Link-Preview/blob/master/lib/link_preview.dart). It worked for me and it is not too long (there are only 2 relevant files):

- [`lib/link_preview.dart`](https://github.com/prolongservices/Flutter-Link-Preview/blob/master/lib/link_preview.dart)
- [`lib/helper/fetch_preview.dart`](https://github.com/prolongservices/Flutter-Link-Preview/blob/master/lib/helper/fetch_preview.dart)